# Rails ActiveAdmin showing attributes from different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
 index do
   column :email
   column :first_name
   column :surname
 end
end
```

app/models/user.rb

```
  has_many :tasks
```

app/models/task.rb

```
  belongs_to :user
```

I have all the attributes in the User model. Is it possible to call those attributes in the Task model. I tried to look up for it but couldn't find anything suitable. For example:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Task do
  index do
   column :email
   column :first_name
   column :surname
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can! For example:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Task do
  index do
    column "Email" do |task|
      task.user.email
    end
    column "First name" do |task|
      task.user.first_name
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm getting undefined method `user' for Task

Comment: It's strange. Because `task` belongs_to `user`, so it must have method `user`. Even when a task doesn't belong to any users, `task.user` will return nil, then we'll have a different error message, like undefined method `email` for nil. Can you try `task.user_id`?